Protection from surveillance
Is there any way I can prevent my SMS messages from bieng proxied between me(the target) and listening posts with a TLS/SSL SIC?
Not a criminal I promise. Lol I'm a veteran patriot concerned for my privacy. Thanks for any help. I'm also looking to change operating systems. Going from windows to freebsd. Any suggestions?
I haven't tried anything yet. Just looking for advice and suggestions
